# Getting oracle error when trying to set date using c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, date

Have been looking for the answer to this all morning but not found anything that works for me. am using this code to try to change a date value in oracle database, but keep getting the oracle error 'ORA-1843: not a valid month':

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

OracleConnection closeDate = new OracleConnection(oradb);

OracleParameter[] prm = new OracleParameter[2];

closeDate.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
prm[0] = cmd.Parameters.Add("paramDate", 
               OracleDbType.Date, "05/02/2015", ParameterDirection.Input);
prm[1] = cmd.Parameters.Add("paramCRN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "16118009", 
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Connection = closeDate;
cmd.CommandText = "update vec_complaint set CLOSURE_DATE = :1 where ID = :2";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
closeDate.Close();
closeDate.Dispose();
```

I'm guessing that I need to state the date format of DD/MM/YYYY somehow but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

Dates have no format, they are binary values, just like as decimals, doubles, floats. Formats have meaning only when they are rendered to strings or parsed from strings.

Assuming that `CLOSURE_DATE` is a date-typed column, not a (n)varchar field, you only have to pass the DateTime object as a parameter value:

```
var myDate=new DateTime(2015,09,29);
prm[0] = cmd.Parameters.Add("paramDate", OracleDbType.Date, myDate, 
                            ParameterDirection.Input);
```

In fact, it's good practice to always pass DateTime objects around instead of date or time strings. Text should be parsed to DateTime or TimeSpan immediately upon input, when you know what the text format and/or user locale is. Trying to determine the format 2 layers down, especially in web applications, is neither easy nor safe.

In your case, you could use a DatePicker or Calendar control on the input form to retrieve the closure date as a DateTime object, then pass this to the data access code.

Comment: Had a separate issue with committing the transaction, but it now works using your example. Thanks for the answer